# C# file Printing as per PDF or Excel or Word or Note pad file Template

Tags: c#, file, printing

i want to print from C# as per PDF or Excel or Word or Note pad template

Answer (score 1):

For Pdf i can recommend you [iTextSharp](http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/)

I have never worked with others, sorry. But for iTextSharp, i can say that it is really easy to use.